# How does EnableCollectionSynchronization work?

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

There are several posts that explain the usage of BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization. E.g. [BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization mystery in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19734782/bindingoperations-enablecollectionsynchronization-mystery-in-wpf) or [Using BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21720638/using-bindingoperations-enablecollectionsynchronization)

However, my understanding of a "lock" does not match the behavior of the following demonstration.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var itemsLock = new object();
    var items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(items, itemsLock);

    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        lock (itemsLock)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("task inside lock");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            items.Where(m => m == "foo").ToArray();
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("task outside lock");
    });

    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Debug.WriteLine("UI thread add..");
    items.Add("foo");
    Debug.WriteLine("UI thread add..done");
}
```

Due to the lock, I expected Debug Output like this:

```
task inside lock
UI thread add..
task outside lock
UI thread add..done
```

But I find an Debug Output like this:

```
task inside lock
UI thread add..
UI thread add..done
task outside lock
```

Background info: I occasionally experience InvalidOperationExceptions "collection was modified" when running LINQ queries on a frequently changed ObservableCollection. This lead me to breaking it down to the previous sample. Then I found that my assumption of how EnableCollectionSynchronization works is wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should synchronize *all* access to the collection using the same lock, i.e. you should lock around the call to `Add`:

```
lock (itemsLock)
    items.Add("foo");
```

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.enablecollectionsynchronization?view=netframework-4.8) is pretty clear on this:

> To use a collection on multiple threads, one of which is the UI thread that owns the `ItemsControl`, an application has the following responsibilities:

- Choose a synchronization mechanism.
- Synchronize **all** access from the application to the collection using that mechanism.
- Call `EnableCollectionSynchronization` to inform WPF of the mechanism.
- ...

Comment: Shame on me - I must have been blind. Somehow I thought that BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization makes my ObservableCollection thread-safe. All it however does is sharing the lock object with the WPF Binding.